# Including the Zend framework not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to include the Zend framework, but I keep getting this error,

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Json.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/www/users/eyelogicy/zone.eyelogic.co.za/weskom/form/classes/ZendFramework/Zend/Json/Decoder.php on line 25
```

here is the PHP code I am using to include the framework,

```
set_include_path('classes/ZendFramework' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Zend/Json/Decoder.php';
```

Any ideas?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try an absolute path for the include path.

[Using absolute path is also a good practise advice](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html):

> One trivial optimization you can do to increase the speed of class loading is to pay careful attention to your include_path. In particular, you should do four things: use absolute paths (or paths relative to absolute paths), reduce the number of include paths you define, have your Zend Framework include_path as early as possible, and only include the current directory path at the end of your include_path.